# How to append html element as a first element in an exist body using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I used `$('body').append('MY HTML elements')` but this code add these elements to the end of the body, i want to add as a first element inside the body.

How to do that using JQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the [`prepend`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend) function:

```
$('body').prepend('My HTML elements');
```